# maximum number of quarters using 10 dollars

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

A shopkeeper keeps 25% of the amount given as commission and returns the remaining back, for example if you give him 1$ he will return back 3 quarters. What is the maximum number of quarters you can get back if you have ten dollars.

Comment: Questions: How does the shopkeeper return change? Does he give "optimal change", or "what we ask for" - meaning if i give him 2 dollars will he give me a 1-dollar bill + 2 quarters back, or will he give me 6 quarters if i ask nicely? :) Also: What does my original money pile look like? is it a 10-dollar bill or ten 1-dollar bills?

Comment: Assuming the shopkeeper always returns 'optimal' change using the standard greedy change algorithm then, using the notation (dollars given, dollars and cents returned, quarters received), after the following transactions (10.00,7.50,2)(7.00,5.25,1)(5.00,3.75,3)(3.00,2.25,1)(2.00,1.50,2)(1.00,0.75,3) you end up with 12 quarters. I presume this is what the questioner was asking as the alternative, 30 quarters achieved by asking for your 7.50 change from a single 10.00 dollar transaction to be all in quarters, seems to be too simple.

Answer (score 3):

I must be missing something...

> 30
>  Ask him for 7.50 change in quarters. That is 30 quarters.

Comment: Also, if you have ten 1-dollar bills, you can repeat the example given, giving $1 each time and getting 3 quarters back each time, which will give the 30 quarters you wanted.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting in the answer, that 30 quarters is the most you can get (if you have no quarters at the start, and only $1 bills, because you lose exactly 25% and have only quarters left) - as long as these are the restrictions intended...

Comment: @PiotrPytlik  think the puzzle was meant to be recursive.  i.e. now you have \$7.50 so repeat the process.  At least, that is the only way I see it getting interesting.

Comment: @Trenin this is problematic, because how do we know how the change is given? Maybe the shopkeep is generous (in a sense) and gives only quarters back in change? Or maybe he always gives the biggest nominal back, so he'd give a 5$, 2$, and 2 quarters?

Comment: @PiotrPytlik Lets assume you can get back the number of quarters you ask for, you just have to request them.  In some cases, perhaps getting non-quarters will give you better flexibility on your next iteration, since you need to make a number divisible by 4.

Comment: @Trenin Well, if you can get as many as you want, then again look at my comment, i think 30 quarters is the max you can get, because you're exchanging all your money for quarters, and losing only as much as you have to (25%), and if i can ask for 30 quarters and get them, then this is the best option.

Comment: @PiotrPytlik that is why I think the puzzle is missing something.  As it is stated, this is obviously the right answer.  But if you got to sum up all the quarters you ever received, then at least it is not trivial.

Comment: Is no one gonna give me an upvote for right answer?? :o)  :o)

Comment: @Ben Ugh, fine :P Even though the question currently isn't clear :)

Comment: @PiotrPytlik   :o)